# Batch if else statement not working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I'm writing a little program but I have a problem with an if else statement.

```
@echo off 
set /p points= 
echo %points% 
echo 1x5= 
set /p 15= 
if %15%==5 ( 
    echo well done! 
    set /a points=%points%+1 
) else ( echo wrong! )
pause 
echo %points% 
pause
```

Even if I fill in a wrong answer, it still ads 1 point to my points and says "Well done!"

(BTW: got some problems with inputting the code, don't now if you will be able to read it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an argument is included in the command line when calling the batch file, it is referenced from code as `%1`, `%2`, ... for the first, second, ... parameters.

In your code, when you write `if %15%==5 ...`, `%15%` is interpreted as first parameter to batch file (`%1`) followed by a 5 and a non escaped non paired percent sign that is discarded by the parser. So, if the batch file has no input arguments and `%1` is empty, your if code is executed as `if 5==5 ...`

As a general recomendation, variables in batch files "should" never start with a number, as they will be considered as input arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p points= 
echo %points% 
echo 1x5= 
set /p 15= 
if !15!==5 ( 
    echo well done! 
    set /a points=!points!+1 
) else ( echo wrong! )
pause 
echo !points! 
endlocal
pause
```

MC MD explained why your code does not work.Here's a way to make it work.